# How to get if user click on use patterns button or user moves to patter pin screen from biometric prompt with Flutter - local_auth?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

Is there any way we can detect when user navigate to password/pin screen when clicking on use patterns button or when system redirects them after some wrong attempts?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No i did not found any solution

Comment: So, we do get the callback on the native side, but the local_auth plugin doesn't send it to the flutter side, I ended up making changes on the top of  local_auth plugin's implementation.